# How could I apply Bootstrap's grid system to a form layout?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to assign column (widths) to form controls I am trying to add to a certain page:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: cyan;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Abc</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: tomato;">
      <!--<div class="form-group">
      <label for="def">Def</label>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Check me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Def</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: blue; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Ghi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: green; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Jkl</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just using regular `<input type="text">` elements won't break the layout. When I am trying to remove the second `form-group` and replace it by a `form-group` containing a checkbox (see comment in the code), the layout seems to break. How am I to fix this?

[image: Unwanted space]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: cyan;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Abc</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: tomato;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="def">Def</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Check me
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: blue; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Ghi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: green; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Jkl</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is for each `form-group` to stay separated so that I can assign individual `col-*`'s to each.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, that your "checkbox-form-group" is at a lower height then the "input-formgroup".

You could easily solve this issue by setting the same `height` to all `form-grops` like in the example below.

> Furthermore you should place your `row` inside a `container` or
>   `container-fluid, because the`row`-class have got a negative margin.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: cyan; height: 74px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Abc</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: tomato; height: 74px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="def">Def</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Check me
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: blue; color: white; height: 74px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Ghi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: green; color: white; height: 74px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Jkl</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**An Other way to solve your issue is to use bootstraps `.clearfix`.**

In this case you have to add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` between your columns, like in the example below.

> [click here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-responsive-resets) to learn more about clearfix.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: cyan;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Abc</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: tomato;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="def">Def</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Check me
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: blue; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Ghi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: green; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Jkl</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Here is a third solution for you:**

The "height problem" occurs because the columns use float:left, so you could get rid of it by using `display: flex; instead`. For this you have to do some css-changes like:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

But, to not overwrite bootstrapp-classes i would not do this on the class `.row`. I would use a new class named like `flexrow`.

> note that you have to add column-classes for lower resolutions, to make sure the grid is working on lower resolutions, too.

```css
.flexrow {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexrow > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flexrow">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" style="background-color: cyan;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Abc</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" style="background-color: tomato;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="def">Def</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Check me
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: blue; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Ghi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color: green; color: white;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="abc">Jkl</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are setting a fixed `height` to the columns? Why would I require to do such a thing? What if my `form-group` becomes bigger for for any certain reason than set height?

Comment: if you'll not use fixed heights to your columns you could add the needed margin to your checkbox, to set it height equal to the other form-elements.

Comment: I can't just set a margin to the checkbox, what if the form control requires more than just a single checkbox? I am trying to come up with a design here that takes into account that the form might be changed in content.

Comment: take a look at my updated answer. an other way to solve your issue is using bootstraps `.clearfix` :)

Comment: So everytime I use checkboxes in forms I should add an element right after its column with `.clearfix` class as well then, because else it, these form controls are to break the layout? Hasn't Bootstrap come up with anything of the sort to apply certain layout to forms? Your solution works fine though. It just seems a bit odd.

Comment: you could add an `cleafix-element` between each `form-element` to get rid of breaking your layout. Thats the way bootstraps grid-system works, unfortunately.

Comment: The downside of using `clearfix` however is that when one would decide to change the `col-*` layout before the clearfix, the elements below the clearfix [won't stick](https://jsfiddle.net/to2h8eqr/) to any available space: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/IQRS2sj) . At least I know that the problem has something to do with the difference in height of the `col-*`'s content.

Comment: @Barrosy I've found an other, third, solution for you. Take a look at my edited Answer.

Comment: Yes I think so although I always try to refrain from editing Bootstrap layout elements (the Bootstrap layout would basically be "broken" which might "confuse" developers reading my code). The new version of Bootstrap uses `flexbox` for layout by default so maybe I should take a look at how things are fixed within that version. I will see if I could apply your solution to my problem.